# iPhone write to file (alternative directory)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod-touch

New to iPhone 3.2, Apple introduced File-Sharing support.  Details can be found at https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009337-SW1 .

Now, most examples floating around in the web demonstrates writing to the documents directory.  What if I want to write files from my app but I don't want the user to be able to see it via iTunes?  I'm looking at the Files and Networking section of the iPhone OS Programming Guide and I'm unsure what would be a good alternative to the documents directory for writing files to hide from the user and not be rejected by Apple's review team.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW10 is the link to the Files and Networking iPhone OS Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data doesn't need to persist each launch you could use the Temps folder. Aptly named, it is a volatile (across launch) folder.

Comment: Maybe I should have made it a multi-part question.  The temps folder makes sense for non persisting across launch.

What If I do want it to persist across launch?

Comment: If you want to persist: and backup: use Documents
if you don't want to backup: use Library/Caches

As perscribed in the docs linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library directory instead of the document directory:

```
// get the library directory:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// make a file name to write the data to using the library directory:
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myfile", libraryDirectory];

// Save data
[myData writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```